# Self producing class not working as I thought, why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, uiview

Im trying to make a self producing class like this:

```
Test *test = [[Test alloc] init];
[test setFrame:frame];
[test setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
[self addSubview:test];
```

This is a `UIView` subclass and this code is inside the `initWithFrame:` method. The class `Test` is its own name, self-producing.

Now the problem I've encountered, I added a breakpoint on the first line you can see above and I see that it never goes through the first line and just creates a new instance but never adds it to the view. Is this not possible or should I "study" more how to do it properly?

Image how it looks like: [image: Image of xCode]

As you can see it never gets past the first line.

Comment: So `Test` is a `UIView` subclass and inside `Test`'s `initWithFrame:` method you're executing that code where you crete yet another `Test` instance (using `init` this time) and you want to add it to the original `Test` instance?

Comment: @LuisCien That is correct, Ive tried with the initWithFrame instead of init but same thing happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I get it now. The problem with your code is that you're forgetting that `initWithFrame:` is `UIView`'s designated initializer method. So, even if you call `[[Test alloc] init]` that `init` call will call `initWithFrame:` itself thus creating an infinite loop.

**EDIT**

In iOS there is a notion of a "designated" initializer. Whenever you have several "init" methods you have to make one of them the "designated" init. For example, `UIView`'s designated initializer is `initWithFrame`. This means that all other init methods will call it under the hood, even init.

This is how `UIView`'s `init` method looks like:

```
-(id)init {
    return [self initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
}
```

This means that even if you instantiate your class as [[Test alloc] init], `initWithFrame` will be called anyway by `UIView`.

Now, you overrode `initWithFrame:` inside your `Test` class and you're also creating another `Test` instance inside that method which is calling again `initWithFrame:`

```
// the init call you have inside this method is calling initWithFrame again beacause
// you're referring to the same Test class...
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // This line here is creating the infinite loop. Right now you're inside
        // Test's initWithFrame method. Here you're creating a new Test instance and
        // you're calling init... but remember that init calls initWithFrame, because
        // that's the designated initializer. Whenever the program hits this line it will 
        // call again initWithFrame which will call init which will call initWithFrame 
        // which will call init... ad infinitum, get it?
        Test *test = [[Test alloc] init];

        [test setFrame:frame];
        [test setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [self addSubview:test];
    }
}
```

**EDIT2: One possible workaround**

One thing you can do to prevent this is to declare a `static bool` variable (flag) to
indicate whether or not `Test` should keep on creating more instances of itself:

```
static BOOL _keepCreating = YES;

@implementation Test

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) 
    {
        // Remember to set _keepCreating to "NO" at some point to break
        // the loop
        if (_keepCreating) 
        {
            Test *test = [[Test alloc] init];
            [test setFrame:frame];
            [test setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            [self addSubview:test];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: The same thing happens when I use the initWithFrame :( Im very confused why this isn't working.

Comment: Let me elaborate a bit more... I'll update my answer

Comment: Mhm, so I cant achieve what I want as easy as I thought?

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure what you want to achieve. Do you want to have a "Factory" method that creates and configures an instance of `Test` for you?

Comment: The reason Im trying to make as you said a "factory" is to make a pathfinder, and what I want it to do is create instances of itself until it finds the path and then backtrace the shortest path via superview. And I thought it would work this way but it seems it doesn't.

Comment: Well, one thing you can do is put your code inside an `if` clause to stop `Test` of creating instances of itself at some point. It's not that your program is breaking. What's going on is that it's trapped in an infinite loop. If you break the loop everything will work fine. So I'd recommend that when you find the "path" you want set some flag to zero to stop the loop.

Comment: It seems that the loop has to stop before it continues the code xD, thanks for the help! It works the way I want now :D

Answer (score 1):

You've written an infinite loop. It's not about `-init` or `-initWithFrame:`. Each call to init creates another Test instance, which creates another Test instance, which creates another Test instance...

I would instead create the subview as a property of Test, like this:

```
@interface Test : UIView
@property ( nonatomic, readonly ) Test * testSubview ;
@end
```

Then create a lazy-initting accessor for `testSubview`:

```
@implementation Test

-(Test*)testSubview
{
    if ( !_testSubview )
    {
        Test * view = [ [ Test alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectZero ] ;
        [ self addSubview:view ] ;
        _testSubview = view ;
    }
    return _testSubview ;
}

-(void)layoutSubviews
{
    [ super layoutSubviews ] ;
    [ self.testSubview setFrame:self.bounds ] ; // testSubview will be created if it doesn't exist...
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

What is it you are trying to accomplish?

You're calling `initWithFrame` as well as just straight `init` which is a little odd.

Depending on what the rest of your code looks like you could get into infinite loop territory, creating and endless stream of `Test` objects and adding them as subviews of themselves.

Perhaps you are looking for a class method that returns a new instance of the `Test` class? That would look like so:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
    return self;
}

+ (id)testWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    Test * test = [[Test alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    return test;
}
```

If you're truly looking for a `Test` object added as a subview of another `Test` object, you would do that in the `testWithFrame:` method.

Comment: I tried adding the testWithFrame: and used it when allocating the new Test but it still does the same thing :(